# Android Tab View unable to getIntent()

Tags: java, android, view, tabs

I am trying to do some tab in my Android project. Here is my tab main page:

```
public class EventDetailMain extends FragmentActivity {
Context context = this;

ViewPager Tab;
EventDtlTabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
ActionBar actionBar;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.event_detail_main);
    TabAdapter = new EventDtlTabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    Tab = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });
    Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    // Enable Tabs on Action Bar
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }

        public void onTabSelected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // on tab selected show respected fragment view
            Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }
    };

    // Add New Tab
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Event Detail")
            .setTabListener(tabListener));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Chat Room")
            .setTabListener(tabListener));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Drop Review")
            .setTabListener(tabListener));
}
```

And the content of my first tab:

```
public class EventDetail extends Fragment {
Context context;
View eventDetail;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    eventDetail = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_detail, container, false);
    context = this;
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Event eventModel = (Event) i.getSerializableExtra("eventObj");
}
```

}

However, I am getting error message "Type mismatch: cannot convert from EventDetail to Context" at the context = this and "The method getIntent() is undefined for the type EventDetail" at the getIntent().

Any ideas? Is it because I did not extends Activity?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I am getting error message as such:

```
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:116)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:837)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1053)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2257)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1240)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2628)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:982)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
11-13 20:24:49.634: E/AndroidRuntime(16503):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In Fragment you have getActivity(). From there you can use getIntent().

**Edit** so:
First mistake - *context = this;* should be *context = getActivity();*
Second mistake - *getIntent()* should be *getActivity().getIntent();*

EDIT2:
so you have a third mistake :D You need to return a View :

**return eventDetail;**

And also, you are not using eventModel anywhere.

Comment: After changing to what you've suggested, I am getting the error message as edited portion. Any ideas?

Comment: Okay I solved it already. But is there anyway to change the tab text color? Because it's currently white color text and the tab background color was white as well.

Comment: There are a lot of things awkward in your code listing. You shouldn't use capitalized names for variables in Java. It makes it very hard to read (calling static methods vs instance methods and such). Capital names are for classes only. You haven't shown the EventDtlTabPagerAdapter implementation which would show how you assign fragments to tabs.

Comment: I would also suggest to try out a new project using "Tabbed app" template. It will guide you through the process...

Comment: But by any chances, do you know how to customize tab in Android? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910091/android-changing-tab-text-color

Answer (score 0):

you need to `setArguments` while attaching the fragment to via `Fragmentmanager` and you can send `Bundle` as an argument like this.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
EventDetail  toOpenFragment = new EventDetail();
bundle.putInt("index", 1);
toOpenFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

and to receive this passed `int` in fragment use like this.

```
final int index = getArguments().getInt("index");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple just use your activity intent by calling

```
 getActivity.getIntent();
Intent  catid_intent ;    


catid_intent = getActivity().getIntent();
  //  sharePref = SharePref.getInstance(getActivity());
    String cat_id = catid_intent.getStringExtra("cat_id");
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cat id premium" + cat_id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```